# Python, сокеты, Bluetooth, RFCOMM

Tags: python, сокет, bluetooth

Доброго времени суток!

---

Конкретизирую и повторюсь для лучшего понимания:

1. Работаю в среде `Spyder 3.0.2 (Python 3.5), ОС Windows 10 Pro`
2. Использую штатный модуль `Bluetooth` ноутбука для связи по протоколу `RFCOMM` с Bluetooth-модулем `HC-06`
3. Использую модуль `PyBluez`

---

Упрощённый код скрипта (опущен процесс поиска и подключения по заданному имени):

```
import bluetooth

bluetooth_addr = '20:16:01:11:67:40'
socket_port = 1

socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
socket.connect( (bluetooth_addr, socket_port) )
```

Код рабочий, подключение происходит, данные передаются.

Однако проблема с функцией `socket.recv (buffsize)`. Она намертво зависает в случае если число доступных байт в буфере сокета меньше аргумента функции - `buffsize`... Что означает необходимость знать число байт находящихся в буфере сокета для исключения сбоев в работе.

Вижу два пути решения проблемы - каким-то образом узнать число байт в буфере сокета, или же использовать таймауты.

Описано и работает решение с использованием таймаута:

```
In [1]: import bluetooth

In [2]: bluetooth_addr = '20:16:01:11:67:40'

In [3]: socket_port = 1

In [4]: socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

In [5]: socket.settimeout (1)

In [6]: socket.connect( (bluetooth_addr, socket_port) )

In [7]: socket.recv (1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-30e8d180471b>", line 1, in <module>
    socket.recv (1)

  File "C:\Users\123\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pybluez-0.22-py3.5-win-        amd64.egg\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 84, in recv
    return bt.recv (self._sockfd, numbytes)

OSError
```

однако по ряду причин оно неприемлемо.

---

В обсуждении было предложено использовать переменную `socket.MSG_DONTWAIT`, однако такой переменной в классе `BluetoothSocket` нет.

Так же было дано уточнение:

> | >>> import socket >>> socket.MSG_DONTWAIT 64 сокет не ваш объект, а модуль – eri

Смысл которого до меня всё же не дошёл. Для проверки в консоли IPython выполнил такой код:

---

```
In [1]: import bluetooth
In [2]: 

In [3]: import socket

In [4]: socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

In [5]: bluetooth_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices()

In [6]: bluetooth_devices
Out[6]: ['20:12:11:22:87:98', '20:16:01:11:67:40', 'E4:E0:C5:C2:34:26']

In [7]: socket.connect( ('20:16:01:11:67:40', 1) )

In [8]: socket.MSG_DONTWAIT
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-8-1b2974ae0a63>", line 1, in <module>
  socket.MSG_DONTWAIT

AttributeError: 'BluetoothSocket' object has no attribute 'MSG_DONTWAIT'
```

---

И так  - что я делаю не так? И всё же, есть ли возможность через класс `BluetoothSocket` узнать число байт в его буфере для реализации не зависающего скрипта?

Comment: можно читать с `flags=socket.MSG_DONTWAIT` и в этом случае будет возвращаться то, что есть в буфере. Полученные данные анализируете и если не хватает - читаете ещё.

Comment: К сожалению нормально вставить код не вышло. Суть в том что pybluez не имеет такого атрибута как `MSG_DONTWAIT`

Comment: Обычно socket.recv(bufsize) может вернуть меньше чем bufsize байт. Если вы поставите timeout и recv(101) выбрасывает исключение вместо возвращения уже доступных 100 байтов, то реализация сломана.

Comment: Ага, на ОС Linux так и работало - если в буфере данных меньше чем запрошено - возвращало всё что есть в буфере. Однако под Windows работает как описано выше... А кросплатформенность нужна

Comment: `>>> import socket
>>> socket.MSG_DONTWAIT
64`
сокет не ваш объект, а модуль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему не воспользоваться методом `socket.setblocking(False)` и читать байты в бесконечном цикле пока они там есть или до определенного символа.

Вот так:

```
msg = ""
socket.setblocking(False)
while True:
    try:
        b = socket.recv(1)
        msg += b.decode()
        if "/r/n" in msg:
            break
    except BluetoothError:
        pass
```

В третьем блоке кода у вас лишний импорт `import socket`, так как вы его не используете и заменяете на `BluetoothSocket`.

Comment: > В третьем блоке кода у вас лишний импорт import socket, так как вы его не используете и заменяете на BluetoothSocket. - это по совету из комметариев пытался обратиться к переменным класса `socket`

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что разблокировка сокета функцией `socket.setblocking(False)` даёт мгновенную отработку `socket.recv(buffsize)`?

Comment: Да именно так. Если при вызове `socket.recv` нет данных выбрасывается исключение BluetoothError. И выполнение программы идет дальше.

Comment: Есть проблема - модуль PyBluez работать с собственными исключениями отказывается наотрез. Только `OSError`. Но это уже тема отдельного вопроса.